# Validating drop down list

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, html-select

I Have a dropdownlist in an aspx page, I am populating the dropdownlist using a datatable. How can i apply a requiredfield validator to this dropdownlist.? Plz help me

Comment: Please post the code [that you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx)  for the selected item's `Value` that is selected first:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" 
    InitialValue="-- Please select --" 
    ErrorMessage="Please select something" />

 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>-- Please select --</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: @RinshadHameed: Doesn't matter. You have an item which is your default item similar to my "please select", haven't you? Note that i've used `AppendDataBoundItems=true`, but you can also use [`Items.insert(0, "--please select--")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffx2x2y2.aspx). However, use the `InitialValue` property to specify the item which means "not selected" for the `Validator`. That can also be an ID if you have set `DataTextField` **and** `DataValueField`. For example "-1" for your default item.